# Parsing errors when i try to create pie chart using d3js

Tags: d3.js, pie-chart

I am trying to create pie charts using d3js. I dont face any issues when i used simple json file. But later when i tried to use slightly more complex json, i am getting these 2 errors.

```
Error: Problem parsing d="M0,-300A300,300 0 1,1 NaN,NaNLNaN,NaNA20,20 0 1,0 0,-20Z"    
Error: Problem parsing d="MNaN,NaNA300,300 0 1,1 NaN,NaNLNaN,NaNA20,20 0 1,0 NaN,NaNZ"
```

from my understanding the error is at arcs.append("path").attr("d", arc). but donno how to fix it.

here is the d3js code

```
<div id="sample1">

<script>
    var r = 300;
    var color = d3.scale.category10()
     var canvas = d3.select("#sample1").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 700)
        .attr("height", 700);

    var group = canvas.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(350,350)");

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(20)
        .outerRadius(r);

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .value(function(d) {
            d.children.forEach(function(x) {
                return x.value;
            });
        })
        .sort(null);

    d3.json("js/mydata.json", function(data) {

        var arcs = group.selectAll(".arc")
            .data(pie(data.children))
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "arc");


        arcs.append("path")
            .attr("d", arc)
            .attr("fill", function(d) {
                d.data.children.forEach(function(x) {
                    return color(x.name);
                });
            });

    })
</script>

</div>
```

here is my json

```
{
"name": "All",
"children": [
    {
        "name": "Main1",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Sub1",
                "value": 6.25
    },
            {
                "name": "Sub2",
                "value": 12.50
    },
            {
                "name": "Sub3",
                "value": 6.25
    }
    ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Main2",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Sub4",
                "value": 6.25
    },
            {
                "name": "Sub5",
                "value": 12.50
    },
            {
                "name": "Sub6",
                "value": 6.25
    }
    ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Main3",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Sub7",
                "value": 6.25
    },
            {
                "name": "Sub8",
                "value": 12.50
    },
            {
                "name": "Sub9",
                "value": 6.25
    }
    ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Main4",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Sub10",
                "value": 6.25
    },
            {
                "name": "Sub11",
                "value": 12.50
    },
            {
                "name": "Sub12",
                "value": 6.25
    }
    ]
    }
]
}
```

Updated:

The approach given by "Lars Kotthoff" worked. how ever this approach does not fix my actual problem which i dint mentioned here. The problem is, i want to give a border to all the Main1,Main2,Main3,Main4. it means although there are 12 colors here borders will be only 4 i.e grouping all three colors into one based on ite parent.

Below picture shows my requirement.

[image]

Comment: You have, as you say, a JSON file with a different structure. You'll have to adjust the code to take that into account.

Comment: i did, the code that i posted is from after the adjustments, but still it is not working. so i posted it here.

Comment: You need to pass the nested children to the pie layout -- it doesn't work with nested structures.

Comment: i did, i passed nested children to the pie layout, you can see it from the above code.

Comment: I'm assuming that you want to display a pie chart segment for each of the child segments. For this, it's easier to flatten the array before passing it to the pie layout -- https://vida.io/documents/njtTBrefacpwsX4iA

Comment: The approach given by "Lars Kotthoff" worked. how ever this approach does not fix my actual problem which i dint mentioned here. The problem is, i want to give a border to all the Main1,Main2,Main3,Main4. it means although there are 12 colors here borders will be only 4 i.e grouping all three colors into one based on its parent. I have updated the question with my actual requirement with an image